# Protobuf files converted by SwiftProtobuf don't compile in Xcode 9 / Swift 4

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers, trezor

I'm new to protobuf and am trying to converting the [Trezor protobuf](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-common/tree/master/protob) files to Swift using [Swift-protobuf](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf).

The Trezor protobuf files do not have a `syntax = "proto3";` or `syntax = "proto2";` line in the code. Adding `syntax = "proto3";` results in an error message: `Explicit 'optional' labels are disallowed in the Proto3 syntax`. Converting the files to Swift as-in (without any syntax line) works (Swift-protobuf defaults to Proto2).

Adding the files to an Xcode 9 / Swift 4.0 however, leads to the errors below. The SwiftProtobuf framework has been added to the project using Cocoapods. How do I fix this?

`Use of undeclared type 'Google_Protobuf_EnumValueOptions'`

`Use of undeclared type 'Google_Protobuf_FileDescriptorSet'`

`Use of unresolved identifier 'clearExtensionValue'`